# See the values of variables change while a Java program is running?

Tags: java, variables, report

Consider a java program with many variables and some of them are counters for loops I want to see the values of these variables as they change with time , WITHOUT putting print statements everywhere in my code.

Why ? I think it can help me to debug easily.

```
Example-
int a = 7;  
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  a++;
}
```

As this program runs I want to get live reports like this:

```
t is 0, a is 7, i is 0
t is 3, a is 8, i is 1
t is 12, a is 9, i is 2
(t is time, time factor is NOT necessary though)
```

Comment: If you're using an IDE (and if not, why not?) such as Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or NetBeans, it comes with a built-in debugger for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: yes, I am using eclipse. How does the Eclipse debugger compare to DDD mentioned by LastStar007 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a debugger and put a breakpoint where you want to see the values (in this case at the line with a++). The you can see the value at each iteration.

Most IDEs have debuggers (Intellij IDEA, Eclipse or NetBeans).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debugger. Debuggers will help you keep track of that without actually sending your vars to STDOUT. I recommend DDD because it's free and professionally used. http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/

Note: to avoid confusion about how it works, DDD works on top of JDB, the Java debugger included in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is what debuggers are used for.. to step through your code and check the values of variables.  If you want your code to print out statements every so often, you can use the `Timer` class and `TimerTask` to print out the value of a variable for a specified time interval.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `Debugger`, If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ, then its build in, into it.

**2.** If you are not using any debugger, then you can use `jdb` **The Java Debugger**.
See `JPDA` for the debugger architecture specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't support this if I'm not mistaken but in Intellij IDEA you can setup breakpoint in a way that doesn't stop your application running when hit it but instead evaluates and logs particular expression you specified. The same functionality available for those who use ms visual studio:)